# Spring boot :Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

```
2018-06-07 15:22:45.991  INFO 6212 --- [           main] i.j.springbootstarter.CourseApiApp       : Starting CourseApiApp on DESKTOP-N2HSE58 with PID 6212 (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\STSWork\course-api\target\classes started by admin in C:\Users\admin\Downloads\STSWork\course-api)
2018-06-07 15:22:45.999  INFO 6212 --- [           main] i.j.springbootstarter.CourseApiApp       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-06-07 15:22:46.376  INFO 6212 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@57f23557: startup date [Thu Jun 07 15:22:46 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-07 15:22:50.048  INFO 6212 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-06-07 15:22:50.112  INFO 6212 --- [           main] i.j.springbootstarter.CourseApiApp       : Started CourseApiApp in 6.046 seconds (JVM running for 10.46)
2018-06-07 15:22:50.120  INFO 6212 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@57f23557: startup date [Thu Jun 07 15:22:46 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-07 15:22:50.123  INFO 6212 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Comment: A question featuring only logs and with no context or description needs to be put on hold. Improve this question if you can!

Answer (score 3):

it's seem not like upstairs saying.
today,i create a project but the dependency is not properly,others springboot project runs normal, this is run and report this error. and i add the below dependency into pom.xml and it run normal.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it finally.I read many articles and saw videos.You are facing this issue as dependency are not downloaded properly just delete the .m2 folder and then update your maven project. It will take time to build depending on your net speed. Once done run your project and it will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my problem

1. Delete the `.m2` folder under `C:\Users\<Username>` in Windows
2. Launch your application
3. It will update the Maven dependencies again
4. Once done, run your application and it should run successfully